# Kivy config.ini Not Saving Changes

Tags: python, kivy, ini

So I have an app I built in Python/Kivy. I need the window to not resize, which I have accomplished by putting the graphics/resizable option to 0 in both Python and the config.ini file. In PyCharm, this works. But when I compile to a .exe, it creates a .kivy folder in the root of the user folder its running in. Which I assume is normal, but in this folder there is a config.ini that has resizable set to a 1, so after it's compiled it is resizable. Changing this to a 0 fixes it, but I need this to be permanent and not occur. Not sure where it is pulling that data from. Any ideas?

```
Config.read(_local_dir + '/config.ini')
Config.setdefault('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand')
Config.setdefault('graphics', 'resizable', '0')
Config.setdefault('graphics', 'show_taskbar_icon', '0')
```

Comment: Try adding a `Config.write()`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson I've tried with and without, no go. Maybe the positioning of where it goes matters? I would put it below all of those.

Comment: @JohnAnderson SOLVED: Instead of having all of my config stuff below my multitude of imports, I moved it to the very top before the other imports. That seems to make it take precedence.